# Ubuntu server: Start dropbox.py of a user without logging in

Tags: server, dropbox

I have an Ubuntu server 12.04. User X logins rarely, but I would like to keep his dropbox folder updated. How can I get the dropbox service of user X service to start at boot/reboot without user X requiring to login (to start the service)?

The server is command line only. No GUI.

Answer (score 1):

Try to start dropbox.py from rc.local

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/rc.local
```

and put line

```
/home/x/dropbox.py &&
```

somewhere above `exit 0`

save end exit

This will work if dropbox.py is already configured.

Answer (score 0):

1. Give sudo access to user 'Y'.

   ```
   $ sudo visudo
   userY  ALL = (userX) NOPASSWD: /home/userX/bin/dropbox.py
   ```
2. Run as userY:

   ```
   sudo -H -u userX /home/userX/bin/dropbox.py status
   ```